# Sort by multiple columns, using nulls first on one of them

Tags: postgresql, order-by, sorting

Given a `members` table, having the following columns:

```
  accepted_at datetime
, updated_at  datetime NOT NULL
```

Given this query:

```
select * from members
order by accepted_at DESC NULLS FIRST, updated_at DESC
```

We invariably always want `accepted_at IS NULL` at the beginning of the list, then the most recent members updated following in the list.
The above query prioritizes on the `updated_at` column, so I end up with accepted members at the beginning of list.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood the actual requirement.  When `accepted_at` is null, you want all those at the top and sorted by `updated_at DESC`; when `accepted_at` is not null, you want to disregard actual `accepted_at` and just sort by `updated_at DESC`.  Is that correct?

Comment: i'll try to simplfy : members who did not accepted (accepted_at is null) should always be first (without any further order requirements). Then the others (accepted_at is not null) should be sorted by updated_at

Comment: Thanks. I think my answer does exactly that. If it doesn't, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you want something like this:

```
ORDER BY
  (accepted_at IS NOT NULL) ASC  -- or: (accepted_at IS NULL) DESC – same effect
, updated_at DESC
```